# Extjs Non-editable Combobox Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, extjs4

I have one thing to achieve using ExtJS v4.2 - to have auto-complete feature working with following code:

```
var combo = {
    xtype: 'combobox',
    editable: false,
    displayField: 'type',
    queryMode: 'local',
    store: 'MyStore',
    valueField: 'value'
}
```

What it does is it features auto-complete with `editable` is set to `false` and `queryMode` is `local` - it works perfectly on previous version of ExtJS 4.2. However, I recently updated to ExtJS 4.2 which is more stable but auto-complete does not work with the above code, I need to have this feature working since I already have done much coding with the newer version.

Also, when I try to set `typeahead` to `true` with `editable` to `false` I got this on my console:

`If typeAhead is enabled the combo must be editable: true -- please change one of those settings.`

I don't have this error on the previous version of Ext4.2...

Please help me on this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you want to use combobox autocomplete feature, ure must set `editable` to `true`, don't you?

Comment: Yes, but enabling `editable` to `true` has a delay of autocomplete. I already found an alternative way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks but I found an alternative way without enabling `editable` to `true`. I added a `keypress` event listener to the combobox which filters the data on the store and automatically sets the value on the combobox with the matching record(s) from the store.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set `editable: false` with auto-complete feature. Just set `editable: true` and it will work. Read the documentation of [editable](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Picker-cfg-editable).